# All day, multi day event is moved to wrong date on calendar for day view

Tags: javascript, salesforce, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Event : Product Booking is set to be starting on March 9th, and ending on the 11th, but the calendar displays it as ending one day too early for day view grid. But there's no issue in displaying all day with week grid view. I have attached screen shots for reference. Can you please help ?

**Week View Grid Image:**
[image: Week Grid]

**Day View Grid Image:**
[image: Day Grid]

**Code:**

```
eventDataTransform: function(eventData) {
  console.log('EventDataStart-->' + eventData.start);
  console.log('EventDataEnd-->' + eventData.end);
  /*var m = moment(eventData.end);
  var roundDown = m.startOf('day');
  var day2 = moment(roundDown).add(1, 'days')
  eventData.end = day2.toString();
  console.log('EventDataEndAfter-->'+eventData.end);*/
  var dur = eventData.end - eventData.start; //total event duration

  if (dur >= 18000000 || eventData.end == null) { // 5 hours

    eventData.allDay = true;
    eventData.allDaySlot = true;

    console.log('dur-->' + dur);
    //eventData.end needs ammending to 00:00:00 of the next morning
    if (dur > 86400000) {


      var m = moment(eventData.end);
      var roundDown = m.startOf('day');
      var day2 = moment(roundDown).add(1, 'days')

      eventData.end = day2.toString();
      console.log('EventDataEndIf1-->' + eventData.end);
    }

  }
  console.log('eventData-->' + JSON.stringify(eventData));
  return (eventData);
}
```

**Console Log Output:**

Week Grid View:

```
EventDataStart-->Thu Mar 09 2023 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
EventDataEnd-->Sat Mar 11 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Day Grid View

```
EventDataStart-->Thu Mar 09 2023 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
EventDataEnd-->Sat Mar 11 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

and

```
eventData-->{"color":"#FF9800","title":"Cooler | Test Record | Time: 09:00 AM - 06:00 PM","start":"2023-03-09T03:30:00.000Z","end":"Sun Mar 12 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530","scheduleid":"a0z8F000000ElipQAC","userid":"0058F000000tDxiQAE","description":"Time: 09:00 AM - 06:00 PM","popupTitle":"Test Record - ","CAP_Reservations__c":{"type":"CAP_Reservations__c","Id":"a0z8F000000ElipQAC","Name":"CAP-00607","Color__c":"#FF9800","Number_of_Chafing_Dishes__c":null,"Number_of_Chairs__c":null,"Number_of_Air_Movers__c":null,"Number_of_Tables__c":null,"Number_Of_Six_Tables__c":null,"Agent__c":"0058F000000tDxiQAE","Agent__r":{"type":"User","Id":null,"Name":"Rohan Kabra"},"CAP_Items__c":"Cooler","Client__c":"0038F00000IssiVQAR","Client__r":{"type":"Contact","Id":null,"Name":"Test Record"},"Drop_Off_Date__c":"2023-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","Pick_Up_Date__c":"2023-03-09T15:00:00.000Z","Wait_List_Position__c":null,"Number_of_Tents__c":null},"allDay":true,"allDaySlot":true}
```

The code above mark the event as all day if the difference between end date and start date is greater than equal to 5 hours. Also we are adding a day to the end date so that events are correctly marked as per start date and end date on the calendar. Previously before adding a day (refer the code) it used to display one day less for both week grid and day grid. After adding a day to the end date, it displays correctly on week grid but not on day grid.

Expected Result : Order should be displayed correctly with proper end date on day grid calendar view.

Comment: Can you please also show the output of the `console.log('EventDataStart-->' + eventData.start);  console.log('EventDataEnd-->' + eventData.end);` commands, so I can see what the transform is going from and to? Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for you response.
Please find below logs:

Week Grid View:
EventDataStart-->Thu Mar 09 2023 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
EventDataEnd-->Sat Mar 11 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Day Grid View
EventDataStart-->Thu Mar 09 2023 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
EventDataEnd-->Sat Mar 11 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Thanks but please always [edit] your question when you have important information to share, it does not belong in the comments :-)

Comment: Anyway, I forgot to ask, can you also please explain the logic of the transformation of the dates you are doing in the function you showed us? I guess this has something to do with the problem, but before I amend anything, I want to be sure I understand the purpose of what this code is supposed to achieve. Again please [edit] the post to provide a clear explanation of what you're doing, and why.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So at the moment, I cannot reproduce your problem - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNgZJOJ . I have to ask, are you using a `timezone` setting in your calendar anywhere (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timezone). I'm not sure how that would be affecting it, but it's possibly a factor. At the moment, using standard fullCalendar 3 and the data you have provided, I cannot see a problem when I run the code, and so it's very difficult to suggest any kind of solution to the issue you have described.